# How to Fix Google Rich Snippets QAPageError?

Tags: google-rich-snippets

How to Google Rich Snippets  QAPage Error?
My error page 
**https://destek.arifemreeryilmaz.com/sorular/web-sitesi-android-cihazda-renkli-bildirim-cubugu-nasil-yapilir/**
and rich snippets error. how to fix this error.
 Question#suggestedAnswer Error
 QAPage Error

**https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool**

[image: 2 errors]

[image: error 1]

[image: error 3]

Comment: Don’t you understand the errors? Where exactly is your problem here?

Comment: Rich snippets  QAPageError alerts . please view images. how to fix this alert  QAPageError

Comment: I’m asking you, as the warning messages say what’s wrong, where exactly your problem is in fixing it? Don’t you understand the warnings? Did you try fixing it but it didn’t work? …?

Comment: Please post code as a snippet in the question itself, not as an external link or a screenshot.